subprocess.communicate in python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['bc', '-q', '-i'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while True:
    if p.poll() is None:
        data = input("> ")
        data = data + "\n" 
        out, err = p.communicate(data.encode())
        print(out.decode().rstrip())
    else:
        break

using communicate function in the Popen i send the data into the communicate to stdin. in my print function i print the output. but in my kernel input value also printing.i know that is silly question some one explain why is that happen.
output:
python mathserver.py
> 1+2
  1+2
  3

i thought is that problem happens on communicate() function

You tagged as Python 2.7 although your code looks more like Python 3. Please either remove the tag or clarify why you would still need to support Python 2.7.

You ran bc with the -i switch, putting it in interactive mode. In interactive mode, it intentionally echoes back the input. If you want to avoid that, just run bc without the -i switch; interactive mode isn't necessary to consume input interactively (it always consumes from stdin and writes to stdout, interactive mode just turns on the echoing).
If you need to run in interactive mode for some other reason (it might change buffering or the like, I haven't checked), you'll need to manually clean the collected standard output from bc, e.g.:
_, out = out.decode().splitlines()
print(out)

This assumes every back and forth with bc echoes input on one line, and output on the next line; this is the typical case, and your use of input() to collect the input to bc limits the cases where it doesn't apply, but I can't swear it will always be the case. Conveniently, by using unpacking the way I did, if this assumption is violated, you'll immediately get an exception, rather than silently doing the wrong thing.

As a side-note, your loop isn't really doing much for you. When you call .communicate(...), the input is fed to the subprocess while the output is collected, and when all the input has been fed to it, the input is closed and the process is waited on. So on your first loop, bc will run to completion, and p.poll() will not be None on the second loop, so the loop only ever runs once. There are no great solutions for this; .communicate(...) exists because it's hard to do buffered two-way communication with a subprocess correctly without deadlocks, delays, etc. This particular case could probably be made to work with threads (one accepting input from the user and feeding it to bc, one consuming output from bc and printing it to the terminal), but it might require using stdbuf to unbuffer the bc process, and you'd need to be very careful to flush your own input to bc properly.

but i provide the input value after the intractive mode is opened the value was passed through stdin. and then the output value provided my bc can get by stdout. so the output value only can get. but your provided can work can you explain that.

@yokeshwaran: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking? I think you're asking why the value you passed in was echoed, and the answer is, that's how bc -i works. You passed it 1+2, and in interactive mode, it intentionally echoes back "1+2\n3\n". You collected that value and printed it to the terminal yourself. All I changed was that I took the two lines it returned, and threw away the first one (the one that echoed your input).

ok i understand. but my doubt is why interactive echo input also

how to read line by line in stdout

@yokeshwaran: If I change ['bc', '-q', '-i'] to ['bc', '-q'], it doesn't echo the input (the user typing the input for input itself will display as they type, but bc won't echo it a second time), so I'm not sure what the problem is. Reading output from p.stdout is trivial (for line in p.stdout:, where p is the Popen object, you don't call communicate in that case), but it's hard to get right if you need to also feed input to the process (using threads is the easiest, if hacky, solution, with unbuffered or line-buffered low-level I/O being the way to do it without threads).
